# How can I withdraw an edit I proposed?

Tags: support

I proposed an edit to a title on a question which upon further review I then decided would not improve anything and decided I should withdraw my proposed edit.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to do this... is it possible? I considered editing the body to allow me to change the title back (as it would be a new edit) but thought that would look like I was gaming the system for reputation. What's  the correct approach?

Comment: It can probably be rejected as a suggested edit... if someone rejects it before others approve it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way within the SE software for you to withdraw an edit.  In addition, further edits are blocked while one is pending.  The best bet is to ask somebody with edit-review privileges or a moderator to reject your edit.  The request should be accompanied by a link.  (You can usually find people in chat who can do this, or for this specific case, add a link to your question.)

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much. Ended up sorted it out with @enderland in the watercooler room already.

Comment: @Codingo Be aware that you don't want to get your edits rejected _too_ often, or you'll wind up [temporarily edit-banned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days).

Comment: @JaneS No worries, once off should be ok. Just passed my 2k rep anyway - so no longer an issue